# awk doesn’t always print out header

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to print out a subset of rows from a csv conditionally using awk, and the header doesn’t always get printed out (if it was consistently not printing out it would be better, but the behavior varies).

E.g.:

```
$ cat faults_main_dp_1_faultDate.csv | parallel -k -q --block 100M --pipe awk -F , '$299 > 30 {print $1 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $299}' | head | csvlook
|-------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------|
|  faultDate  | assetId           | faultActiveTime     | faultActiveLatitude  | ambienf             |
|-------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------|
|  2015-03-08 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-03-08T10:52:40 | -0.40950949999999997 | 31.334039688110398  |
|  2015-03-07 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-03-07T15:34:16 | -0.3867394           | 32.2283515930176    |
|  2015-03-07 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL619 | 2015-03-07T17:42:19 | -0.380149841         | 32.7088813781738    |
|  2015-03-06 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-03-06T15:33:15 | -0.354323447         | 33.337738037109396  |
|  2015-03-05 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-03-05T17:38:20 | -0.31172340000000004 | 32.225231170654304  |
|  2015-03-05 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-03-05T15:24:19 | -0.302686065         | 30.0030345916748    |
|  2015-04-20 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL622 | 2015-04-20T19:41:22 | -0.379977226         | 31.8880805969238    |
|  2015-04-18 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | 2015-04-18T06:59:32 | -0.38011753600000003 | 31.6899147033691    |
|  2015-04-09 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | 2015-04-09T18:38:09 | -0.383524776         | 31.0484771728516    |
|-------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+——————————|
```

But:

```
$ cat faults_main_dp_1_faultDate.csv | parallel -k -q --block 100M --pipe awk -F , '$1 < "2014-03-01" {print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $299}' | head -n 5 | csvlook
|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------|
|  2014-02-28 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL619 | -0.369633675         |                     |
|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------|
|  2014-02-28 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL619 | -0.375370562         |                     |
|  2014-02-28 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL620 | -0.291365266         | 23.3389568328857    |
|  2014-02-27 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | -0.38014966200000005 | 30.008481979370103  |
|  2014-02-27 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL618 | -0.38014966200000005 | 31.7841949462891    |
|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+——————————|
```

or:

```
$ cat faults_main_dp_1_faultDate.csv | parallel -k -q --block 100M --pipe awk -F , '$5 == "LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623" {print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $299}' | tail | csvlook

|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------|
|  2015-07-09 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.30150732399999997 | 25.9456386566162  |
|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------|
|  2015-06-14 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.3295847           | 34.0456199645996  |
|  2014-08-13 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.41220685799999995 |                   |
|  2014-10-20 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.415138245         |                   |
|  2015-08-21 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.38848757700000003 | 30.0110931396484  |
|  2015-08-25 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.41773062899999996 |                   |
|  2015-04-21 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.4055466           | 36.1775779724121  |
|  2014-02-18 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.418272376         |                   |
|  2013-12-24 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.3781222           | 21.1109352111816  |
|  2015-03-13 | LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623 | -0.35584770000000004 |                   |
|-------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------|
```

Comment: Since you're using `parallel`, then you have no guarantee that the first line of the file will be output first

Comment: Correct. So, what I did is got the header first (I am importing this into R), then got the main csv without the header and passed the header to the function creating a data frame. If there is a way to just grab the header first, print it out, and then do the rest of the call, that’d be nice.

Answer (score 1):

All conditions apply to all rows, if not satisfied you'll not see the header in the output.  You can do this however,

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print;next}  your condition here{your action here}'
```

this will print the first line without any condition and moves on to the next lines with your existing condition{action}.  If you don't need to full header row but certain fields, you need to specify them as well.

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR==1{print $1,$5,$7,$299;next}  your condition here{your action here}'
```

Comment: Thanks. But why does the first condition print out the header? how’s ‘“ambienf”  > 30’ evaluate to true?

Comment: `awk` can convert numbers to strings for comparison.  For example  `echo "apple" | awk '$1 > 1'` will print apple.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a question about your solution: I think it tries to print out all the columns, but I just need to print out the [names of] just the columns I specified. I tried doing the following, but it didn’t do comparison at all and didn’t print out the header correctly: `awk -F , 'NR==1 {print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $299 ;next} $5 == "LOCOMOTIVE_ALL623" {print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $299}’`.

Comment: Yes, my oversight.  You need to list the columns you want to be printed in the first block as well.  Note that by setting `-vOFS=,` you don't need to quote the commas.  I'm curious what did it print?

Comment: I think the issue is that since I am trying to parallelize my script, it’s parallelizing the whole operation, including printing the first line no matter what. I think I need to make two calls: 1) to print out the header, 2) to print out the tail -n +2. If there is a way to do it in one line, I’d appreciate an advice.